# Is my explanation to this derivative problem correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Basically, I am trying to prove that number 13 relates to the graph of B, but I was wondering if my explanation was correct. Here is the problem and here is what I wrote.

[image: Problem]

From the interval of - ∞ to zero, the function is decreasing, so f ' < 0. The interval from zero to + ∞, the function is increasing, so f ' > 0. The graph that corresponds to this is B because the interval from - ∞ to zero, f ' is below zero on the y-axis and the interval from zero to + ∞, f ' is above zero on the y-axis.

Also, for this problem, is there a more efficient way of saying where the function is increasing or decreasing, rather than saying "in this interval, the function is increasing/decreasing," since there are 5 intervals and doesn't give the points on the axis?

[image: Problem],

Comment: Yes, that looks good!

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: (b) looks like a straight line while 13 looks like a parabola.  It is true that the derivative of a parabola is a straight line which is $0$ at the minimum of the parabola, so here when $x=0$

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you, but I added a new problem and I wondering if there is a much more efficient way of writing and explaining where the intervals are, rather than repeating the same words over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Your explanation is fine, but you could additionally be more specific.

- **Problem (13):** The function $y^\prime$ is linear, so it's a function of the form $y^\prime = kx+d$. Since $(0,0)$ is a point of $y^\prime$ we have $d=0$. We also see the slope $k$ is positive. The function $y$ looks like a parabola and it is going through $0$. Which functions $y, y^\prime$ could be proper candidates?
- **Problem (15):** We see periodical functions $y$ and $y^\prime$ with $y^\prime(0)=0$. The function $y^\prime$ is $y$ shifted to the left by a quarter of a period, i.e. shifted by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Which trigonometric functions $y, y^\prime$ could be proper candidates?